# Firefox file dialog doesn't see cryptomator volumes (vault)

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, firefox, webdav

I have ubuntu 16.04 with firefox (47.0) and [cryptomator 1.1.0](https://cryptomator.org) applications installed.

On my machine has one cryptomator volume (known as [vault](https://cryptomator.org/architecture/)) mounted and it's not visible to any firefox file dialog (open file, output, etc), but it's visible opening a nautilus windows or other application (Ex: chromium) file dialog.

Is it a bug (firefox? nautilus? cryptomator?) or access to these [webdav volumes](https://cryptomator.org/architecture/) is out of scope of firefox specifications? In windows 7, same vault is visible to firefox.

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator/issues/293) in cryptomator github.

1. Vault visible

[image: Vault Visible]

2. Vault not visible on firefox dialog

[image: Vault not visible]

Comment: Try toggling `Ui.allow_platform_file_picker` to `true` in `about:config`: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Ui.allow_platform_file_picker, if it's not already set to `true`.

Comment: The value is already set as  true.

Comment: Cryptomator [Github issue](https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator/issues/293) related has updated: added **type:upstream-bug** and removed **state:to-be-confirmed** labels .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround that seems to do the trick is to create a symbolic link to your mounted vault.

E.g., to put a link in a directory called `~/links`: First make sure your vault is mounted, which will open a nautilus window with your vault. From the nautilus window, right-click on the background and select "Open in Terminal". Then type the following commands:

```
vaultpath=`pwd`
mkdir ~/links
cd ~/links
ln -s $vaultpath vault
```

You should now see a folder called "vault" located in "~/links", that you can open from within Firefox or anywhere else, as long as your vault is mounted.

This worked for me and survived a restart. I guess it is contingent on cryptomator not changing the name of the mount directory.

Comment: It works fine! I'm going to post your suggestion in the related [github issue](https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator/issues/293). It doesn't solve the firefox problem (dav volume hidden on firefox dialog)  but helps a lot. Thanks  @Andy.

Comment: New [github issue #508](https://github.com/cryptomator/cryptomator/issues/508) about this workaround. There's some points that need some atention.